# Errors using expdp with `flashback_time=systimestamp`

Tags: oracle, datapump, expdp

Oracle 11.2.0.1.0 on Windows 2012 Std:

```
expdp '/ as sysdba' full=y directory=exp dumpfile=... logfile=... flashback_time=systimestamp
```

Fails with:

```
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39150: bad flashback time
ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0 
ORA-01877: string is too long for internal buffer
```

Replacing `flashback_time=systimestamp` with `consistent=y` which AFAIK is a backwards compatible way to say the same exact thing also fails with the same errors. Removing those options completely, with no other changes, makes it work.

Still, I *would* like to take a *consistent* backup in addition to RMAN, which yes I do have configured and working. There are various workarounds suggested on the web. For example using `to_timestamp` but none of them seem to be working.

My questions are:

1. Is this a known bug?
2. Are there any settings that could cause this behavior like system locale?
3. I am using a slightly modified version of [this](https://www.krenger.ch/blog/oracle-full-datapump-export-batch/) script and I swear just yesterday it worked fine. I don't recall changing anything, today it doesn't work. Any ideas?
4. Is there a reliable workaround? I am thinking of using `flashback_scn` instead but that will require a separate query beforehand.

**Edit:**

Doubling down on the weirdness here. Each day:

- 00:00-11:59 - errors as above
- 12:00-23:59 - everything works fine

I ran the script repeatedly yesterday evening using `flashback_time=systimestamp` - no errors. Today 7:45am getting errors again from the same script, without modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved. I've had a chance to ask an Oracle DBA who was doing some consulting work for us about this. Turns out it is most likely a bug in how Oracle handles spaces in localized timestamps. A simple workaround is to `set NLS_LANG=american_america.ee8iso8859p2` before running `expdp`.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL850).

It says:

> You can specify the time in any format that the
>   DBMS_FLASHBACK.ENABLE_AT_TIME procedure accepts

So SYSTIMESTAMP should actually work... Though the docs suggest you need to enclose the parameter in quotation marks. Try:

```
FLASHBACK_TIME="SYSTIMESTAMP"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have no idea what's going on but *now* it works again with or without quotes. I have a suspicion that it's somehow connected to time of day. It stopped working around midnight, didn't work in the morning, now it's past noon and and it's working again. Quite frustrating :/ I'm going to test this some more.